# Display Attachments in Webpart

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

whats the problem?

123 should be with bild1.gif and second image with bild2.gif

Comment: Duplicate of this one:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57792/display-attachment-in-webpart

Comment: yea i know ,  but noone is helping me

Comment: That is no reason to add another question - it just reduces the value of the site while annoying the people who might be able to help you. Please edit your original question to improve it if you want to increase the chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

took me some time to understand what you were looking for lol bad on my part but i think i have the right solution for you ;) I've gone through and come up with this code, this link helped me to figure out what was going on :)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929259

ok i think this should work for you

```
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = string.Format("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>");
    query.RowLimit = 10;
    query.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true;
    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

    Repeater1.DataSource = items;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

that is fine and is called after the databound, so its doing the binding and then adding thoes links. To ammend the data whilst its being bound you need to call the itemdatabound event like so:

```
private List<string> arrayList = new List<string>;

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    { 
          HyperLink hp;
          foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
          {

              foreach (string currentAttachmentUrl in item.Attachments)
              { 
                  if (!arrayList.Contains(currentAttachmentUrl)) 
                  { 
                      hp = new HyperLink(); 
                      hp.ID = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString(); 
                      hp.Text = item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + currentAttachmentUrl; 
                      hp.NavigateUrl = item.Attachments.UrlPrefix + currentAttachmentUrl; 
                      arrayList.Add(currentAttachmentUrl); 
                  }
              }
          }

        // add to the repeater 
        e.Item.Controls.Add(hp); 

    } 

}
```

to call the event above you need to add this to the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

I've taken the code that I've done and added it into the new event, your calling the new event where you create the repeater. This should do the trick :)

**EDIT**

I've just amended the code above, it checks the current item in the repeater against the current item in the list, if its the same than it will do the code (hyperlink), please let me know the result as you might need to tweak the if function as i dont know what the two values are weather `e.Item.ItemIndex` starts at 0 or 1 and same with the other :)

hope it helps :)

Comment: When you add the first news with attachment, it doesnt show it in the interface. When you create a second one, the second one doesn't show up, but the first appears. And when you create a third news, third one doesnt show, but the second and first ones attachment appears. BUT(!). The itemid doesnt following the current news

Comment: iv ammended the code, you need to check the values by debugging the line  if (e.Item.ItemIndex == item.ID-1)
and see what values are going in. i put -1 as i belive the item.id starts at 1 rather than 0 like the index http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.id.aspx

Comment: With -1 it show ok But the attachment doesn't follow with the uploaded values. it only stays in place For example Name:Martin Age:22 Attachment:hello.jpg i want that the attachment to be together with Martin and Age and not only that it will display the attachment

Comment: Namely,attachments ​​do not accompany their news

Comment: item.id starts at 1 its true and index at 0 but the problem is like above here , that the attachment doesnt follow with the added item to list it only stays in place in the interface

Comment: Maybe i need a hidden field so the first added item to the list nows that this attachment is togethir with that item?

Comment: i have updated the image at the top.

Comment: yes you can either do it that way or by adding the result into a dataset using code and checking it that way

Comment: i have tried in many ways with hiddenfield but i dont get it to work :(

Comment: ok iv solved one of the issues, i put in a break; in the code as i thought you only want one attachment per item. im looking inot the other issue. please try the code out now :)

Comment: yes i only want one attach per item but the item dont saves the attachment that i upload when i am showing it. Look my image that i have uploaded its 2 images in one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7269/discussion-between-morski-martin-and-ali-sharepoint)

Comment: Hi! i have enabled session state now , but i showes anyway diffirent when uploading attachments, i upload now one attachment it show it when uploading another it overwrites it